# Convert regular json to flare.json for d3.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, d3.js

I have a json like so:

```
{
"a": {
    "x": {
        "y": {
            "a": {}, 
            "z": {}, 
            "b": {}
        }
    }, 
    "c": {}, 
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": {}
        }
    }, 
    "d": {}, 
     ...
    }
}
```

Is there a quick way to convert it to flare.json format?

Like so:

```
{
"name":"a",
"children":[
      {
      "name":"x",
      "children":
            {
              "name":"y",
              "children":[{"name":"a", "size":0},{"name":"z","size":0},{"name":"b","size":0}]

...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Neal I did come up with something fancy! Check out my answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have come up with a series of regex transforms for this.

```
 #replace-this      #with-this

  ^\s*"             \{"name":"
  : \{\},           \},
  : \{\}            \}
  ": \{$            ","children":\[
  ^\s*\},           \]\},
  ^\s*\}            \]\}              


 #in that order
```

and just delete the first and last line (should be an extra `{` and `]}` )

on applying these regex transforms,

this:

```
{
"a": {
"x": {
    "y": {
        "a": {}, 
        "z": {}, 
        "b": {}
    }
}, 
"c": {}, 
"b": {
    "c": {
        "d": {}
    }
}, 
"d": {} 
}
```

}

will become this:

```
{
"name": "a",
"children": [{
    "name": "x",
    "children": [{
        "name": "y",
        "children": [{
            "name": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "z"
        },
        {
            "name": "b"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "name": "c"
},
{
    "name": "b",
    "children": [{
        "name": "c",
        "children": [{
            "name": "d"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "name": "d"
}]
}
```

which can then be used with some of the d3js examples.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to write your own JSON or a function to dynamically change the JSON. Flare.json just follows a schema that adheres to Mike Bostock's d3 files.

I'll give you a hint. The schema that you wrote appears to be (in psuedocode)

```
array("name":"a", "children":array("name":"x","children":array(.....
```

Basically, you need to create a multidimensional array in order to get the desired results. I don't know how you are getting your data, unfortunately, so I can't tell you much more. If using php use the json_encode method

```
echo json_encode($jsonArray)
```

or in javascript use json.stringify

```
var json = JSON.stringify($jsonArray)
```

in order to get the array to turn into json.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest), however this function won't give you the size as desired, even . You might want to format your data accordingly before sending it to the app.

If you want to create a custom function, then you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912966/d3-json-data-conversion/15914716#15914716) answer and iterate on the keys of your object, as it is not even an array.