# i wanto get a result set of neo4j as an json?

Tags: json, node.js, d3.js, neo4j

currently i am doing is represent relation ships of data using d3.js. need to represent it in a tree. My data stored at Neo4j server. And application is design under Express frame work.

```
var cypher = [
                "match (b:Binary)-[r*..1]->(a:Binary)",
                    "where a.Key = '" + data + "'",
                "return collect( distinct b) as dep"].join("\n");
```

execute this query and put the result in to a queue and sequentially execute it. this is for getting all children of the node. But I need to make this not as flat json something like depth. like `

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
......  how can i do it?
```

Comment: I guess you're using the REST API for this: get the response you receive from the query and build your own JS object to map the structure above. Then just stringify it in JSON. And please, use the `params` structure to send the data: it's not nice to have Cypher injections http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-use-parameters

Comment: no I use a npm library Node-neo4j.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [d3's nest function](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) to do this.   This is actually mostly a JSON question, it seems your problem is that you need to start with the JSON output that the RESTful services Neo4J provides, and then transform that into a JSON structure suitable for tree representation in D3.    The nest function will really help with that.

A second option you have is to use a tool like [json2json](https://github.com/joelvh/json2json), which is a more generic tool intended to help transform from one json structure into another.   Under that approach, you write a set of template rules and then translate a data structure.

Comment: But the prob lem is i have multiple parents and mutiple childs.

Answer (score 1):

don't make down votes. i think you can have this answer chiran.

[Generate (multilevel) flare.json data format from flat json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847131/generate-multilevel-flare-json-data-format-from-flat-json?rq=1)

Comment: Ok thanks But i cannot make a upvote of correct here because this is not your own ans..