# Creating a D3.js Collapsible Tree from CSV data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

This might be a slightly silly question for those of you more familiar with d3 but I'm fairly new to it and I can't quite figure out how to get this thing to work:

What I'm trying to achieve is this: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

But I'd like to feed it the data from a flat CSV rather than a JSON.

The problem is that the CSV I have is formatted like so:

```html
Parent Name | Child Name
-------------------------
Parent Name | Child Name
-------------------------
Parent Name | Child Name

so on...
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I know that the d3.csv function works somehow, but I have no idea how to 'plug it' into the example above.

I do apologise, I know this very much sounds like "Do my homework for me", but I've honestly given it a good go and I think I'm stuck.

Thank you. Appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't seen what you are looking for done before, but it is a combination of [creating a tree from flat data](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-generating-a-tree-diagram-from-flat-data) (which requires a bit of data manipulation to finesse it into the correct structure) and the standard [loading data from and external source](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-generating-a-tree-diagram-from-external-data) with d3.

<del>Sadly I'm not able to set up a bl.ock for you to demonstrate live code,</del>EDIT: [Here is a live version](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/fa0f16e271cb191ae85f) of the running code on bl.ocks.org, and the following is the html file which is the combination of the two techniques;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

    <style>

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
 
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the external data
d3.csv("treedata.csv", function(error, data) {

// *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
// create a name: node map
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
 map[node.name] = node;
 return map;
}, {});

// create the tree array
var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
 // add to parent
 var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
 if (parent) {
  // create child array if it doesn't exist
  (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
   // add node to child array
   .push(node);
 } else {
  // parent is null or missing
  treeData.push(node);
 }
});

  root = treeData[0];
  update(root);
});

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Declare the nodesâ€¦
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { 
    return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the linksâ€¦
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", diagonal);

}

</script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following is the csv file I tested it with (named treedata.csv in the html file);

```
name,parent
Level 2: A,Top Level
Top Level,null
Son of A,Level 2: A
Daughter of A,Level 2: A
Level 2: B,Top Level
```

Kudos should go to nrabinowitz for describing the data transformation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847131/generate-multilevel-flare-json-data-format-from-flat-json).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I also found this example which also uses the same principle: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2949981

Comment: Ahh... Well done. I might have guessed that Mike would have described this some time in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the earlier answer is not collapsible. Adding a collapsible version of the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

  <style>
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .node text {
      font: 9px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 120,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20
      },
      width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
      height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      duration = 750;
    var root;

    var i = 0;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
      .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
      .projection(function(d) {
        return [d.y, d.x];
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // load the external data
    d3.csv("d3tree.csv", function(error, data) {

      // *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
      // create a name: node map
      var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
        map[node.name] = node;
        return map;
      }, {});

      // create the tree array
      var treeData = [];
      data.forEach(function(node) {
        // add to parent
        var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
        if (parent) {
          // create child array if it doesn't exist
          (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
          // add node to child array
          .push(node);
        } else {
          // parent is null or missing
          treeData.push(node);
        }
      });



      function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      root = treeData[0];
      root.x0 = height / 2;
      root.y0 = 0;
      console.log(root)
      //  root.children.forEach(collapse)
      update(root);
    });

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
      });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", click);

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".01em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

      nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.target.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          };
          return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
          });
        });

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          };
          return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
          });
        })
        .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });




    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(d);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```