# csv to json for hierarchy tree d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Can  someone help me figure out why my json file isn't being produced. I used a small subset of the data and it worked. When I use the full set I get either and empty array, the first two lines worked, or a cyclic error.

Here is the first few lines of my csv....

```
parent,name,nsize,lsize,type,level,nfill
NR2F2,NNMT,20,3.035224474,black,red,blue
NR2F2,CDH6,20,2.497522953,black,red,blue
NR2F2,LOX,20,2.882828876,black,red,blue
NR2F2,AFAP1L2,20,3.250988851,black,red,blue
NR2F2,KCNG1,20,1.871023523,black,red,blue
NR2F2,THBS2,20,3.556420832,black,red,blue
NR2F2,RHOU,20,4.892457573,black,red,blue
NR2F2,ITIH5,20,1.579040121,black,red,blue
```

and here is the script that I've copied from [Generate (multilevel) flare.json data format from flat json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847131/generate-multilevel-flare-json-data-format-from-flat-json/17849353#17849353)

```
//load csv and copy to global variable  
d3.csv("../jsfiles/nr2f2tbx5hey2json.csv", function(csv_data) { 
        var nested_data =  d3.nest()
          .entries(csv_data);

var dataMap = {};
var dataMap = nested_data.reduce(function(map, node) {
map[node.name] = node;
return map;
}, {});

// create the tree array
var tree = [];
nested_data.forEach(function(node) {
// add to parent
var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
if (parent) {
    // create child array if it doesn't exist
    (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
        // add node to child array
        .push(node);
} else {
    // parent is null or missing
    tree.push(node);
}

});

 //create the root node for the treemap
var root = {};

    // Add the data to the tree
root.name = "Start";
root.children = tree;
console.log(JSON.stringify(root,null, 4));
```

It looks like it errors out after the //create the tree array section

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your data is cyclical?

Comment: It is a list of interactions (parent interactions with source (name). There are some interactions that have a feedback loop. So if 1--> 2, 2-->3, and 3-->1. Would this be the problem? and is there a way to change this script to arrange the json correctly for these feedback loops?

Comment: How do you represent a loop in a hierarchy tree? you can't. That's my guess from the 'cyclical error'. It's found an endless loop 1>2>3>1>2>3... I'm guessing that's the issue. You could do more tests on your data to confirm.

Comment: I was hoping it would work out to 1-->2, 2-->3, and 1-->3. I'm lost on how to change it so that the parents that have targets higher up can change from 3-->1 to 1-->3

Comment: OK so this is all an assumption at this stage. I have added the javacript tag in case someone can help you. I guess you need to recognise this in the code (but this is difficult as the information spans many nodes)