# Convert CSV to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to follow the various instructions (e.g. [How to convert to D3's JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088303/how-to-convert-to-d3s-json-format)) to create a collapsible tree with D3.js.

Here is what I have done so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/L3phF/6/

I have a problem when using `nest()` as `console.log(nest)` shows me only an empty object, but I cannot find the error.

```
var raw = d3.select("#csvdata").text();

var parsed = d3.csv.parse(raw);

// d3.select("#parsed").text(raw); 
// d3.select("#parsed").text(JSON.stringify(parsed));

var data = JSON.stringify(parsed);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.subgroup; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.division; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.product; })
    .entries(data);

console.log(nest);
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Don't turn the nice object d3.csv.parse gives you back into a string! d3.nest() is expecting an object, not a string:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.subgroup; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.division; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.product; })
    .entries(parsed);
```

will give you what you want.