# D3 CSV to JSON adjacency list, how to access node colors?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

Following up on this question, what if I have a node color, how do I access it?  Put it in the nodeByName function somehow?

[How to convert to D3's JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088303/how-to-convert-to-d3s-json-format/11089330#11089330)

I have CSV:

```
source,target,target_node_color
A1,A2,green
A2,A3,blue
A2,A4,blue
```

And I'm drawing my tree exactly like answer above:

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { 
        return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("atlas16.csv", function(error, links) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nodesByName = {};

  // Create nodes for each unique source and target.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    var parent = link.source = nodeByName(link.source),
        child = link.target = nodeByName(link.target);
    if (parent.children) parent.children.push(child);
    else parent.children = [child];
  });

  // Extract the root node and compute the layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(links[0].source);

  // Create the link lines.
  svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "link";})
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Create the node circles.
  svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { 
        return d.y; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.x; });

  function nodeByName(name) {
    return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name});
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the color by adding another parameter for color in the nodeByName function. Look at [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XDNJf3ZOJezh4hBsPsvE?p=preview). See the console to view the color for a node.

```
var parent = link.source = nodeByName(link.source,link.target_node_color),
    child = link.target = nodeByName(link.target,link.target_node_color);
...

 console.log( nodesByName)
function nodeByName(name,color) {
    return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name, color : color}) ;
}
```